# Semantic UI Sidebar making background image of <body> insivible

Tags: javascript, html, background-image, semantic-ui, sidebar

When I click the Semantic UI Sidebar Menu button, the background-image for the  disappears, leaving a plain white background. I have done some research and I found that someone suggested to add something like this to the CSS but I'm having no luck:

```
.pushable > .pusher {
  #FFFFFF url(myurl.png);
}
```

I am new to Semantic and I am not using all of the files with the site.variables and so fourth. Just connecting to it via the internet. If anyone has any tips on how to get past this problem without having to download all of the src files I would appreciate it. Otherwise, I will just have to download all of the files and manipulate it that way. Thanks.

Comment: You most likely won't get much traction here without a working example of the problem, with the applicable code, that we can look at to debug.

Comment: can you please share some code? otherwise it is nor clear which image is changed.